# How to get the state of a toggleButton in a ribbon in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, toggle, wxwidgets, ribbon, togglebutton

I'm building a UI using wxWidgets in windows platform with C++. I have a toggle button in the ribbon. I initialize the button as follows:

```
m_cell_bar->AddToggleButton(RIBBON_CELLSELECTMODE, wxT("Cell Select"), wxBitmap(selectcell_xpm), wxEmptyString);
```

To fulfill the purpose of using a toggle button, I need to assign different events from unchecked->checked and checked->unchecked events. If it was a normal toggle button I would use:

```
buttonid->GetValue()
```

But it's not.. So how can I reach the state?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like they provide a method for getting the checked state of a button (I'm working with 2.9.2). However it looks like you can get it using code like this (I've not tried this, just looked through the wx code):

```
wxRibbonButtonBarButtonBase* button = m_cell_bar->AddToggleButton(RIBBON_CELLSELECTMODE, wxT("Cell Select"), wxBitmap(selectcell_xpm), wxEmptyString);
// Store the "button" pointer for use later
// ...
// Sometime later
if((button->state & wxRIBBON_BUTTONBAR_BUTTON_TOGGLED) == 0)
{
    // Not checked
}
else
{
    // Checked
}
```